# No internet connection - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, kernel

I use Ubuntu since 2 months and I had a problem this morning I could not fix. I have tried many solutions on forums but none worked so far. I hope I will find any help here as I need this computer to work.

**Issue** : Network card is not detected, I do not have access to Wi-Fi, audio and bluetooth. I only have "dummy output" as audio output.

**Clue** : I tried to fix an issue with Ubuntu giving me black screen when computer was put in suspension. To do so I switched my Nvidia driver from 470 to Nouveau. Also I played with the file /etc/default/grub but I think I did not make any permanent change on the end. [Irrelevant]

**Some commands I typed that may be relevant:**

*lspci -k -nn | grep -A 3 -i net:*

```
(base) castaing@castaing-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ lspci -k -nn | grep -A 3 -i net 
    04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:825d]
```

*ip a :*

```
(base) castaing@castaing-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ ip a
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    (base) castaing@castaing-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$
```

*Modprobe :*

```
  (base) castaing@castaing-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ sudo modprobe 8169
    modprobe: FATAL: Module 8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-80-generic
 
  (base) castaing@castaing-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ sudo modprobe r8169
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-80-generic

 
(base) castaing@castaing-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ sudo modprobe 8168
    modprobe: FATAL: Module 8168 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-80-generic


(base) castaing@castaing-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

*Content of the file /etc/default/grub thay may be realted to the issue:*

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

**Update:**
I found a temporary solution: it turned out the problem was the last update with the installation of a new Linux version 5.4.0.80.
With the Advanced Ubuntu option in the boot menu I managed to start with Linux 5.4.0.77 (generic version) and now my Internet is back.
However when running dmesg command I still have some errors shown below :

```
[    0.416717] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
[    0.416721] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
[   17.812417] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[   46.580144] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: secboot: HS load failed, ret 0x0000002c
[   46.580152] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: init failed, -22
```

I did a boot repair but nothing changed

Comment: The clue to fixing it is likely what change(s) did you make in the sesion(s) before you encountered this issue. You've highlighted nvidia which is unrelated to networking in my experience - so why have you linked them?  Did your changes related to nvidia which caused the networking changes?  Please tell us what did, how networking & video relate?  Which kernel stack are you using (LTS releases have two stack choices; some of your messages imply you're using HWE or 5.4 kernel)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe r8169` and also: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I linked change of drivers to this problem because since I tried to fix the issue I had (now resolved) I have this new problem. I don't know if it's related. I edited asked commands.

Comment: The only change I did was to edit /etc/default/grub but then I erased all changes. I also switched from nvidia-driver-470 to Nouveau.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the kernel 5.4.0-80. I simply restarted using kernel 5.4.0-77 to fix the problem.
To do so just go in the Advanced Ubuntu Option in boot menu and select what kernel you want to boot with.
Hope this will help someone.